# Show tags on top when reviewing questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, review-queues

When reviewing questions, I sometimes want to skip a question if it is related to a language or a framework I'm not familiar with or don't have any opinions on. So I would like to check the tags to see what it's all about, and if they are totally bizarre, I'd simply press skip and move on. Now, some questions are very long and I have to go all the way down to find the tags on the bottom.

To sum up, it would be nice if I could see the tags on top instead.

Comment: I would also concur with this point. Often times, the main subject/language is not included in the title because it is inferred from the tags. Placing tags near the title seems logical to me.

Comment: That's a very nice idea -- maybe at the top and in bold or something like that. It's really the first thing I want to see, and since posts vary in length, something I often have to scroll down to.

Comment: You can filter the questions by tag. So, you can get only related question to review. http://i.stack.imgur.com/DYUpA.png.

Comment: @ketan Not in Triage AFAIK

Comment: Maybe even only allow someone to review a question if they have a least one up-vote in one of the tags.  Or at least order the questions they are reviewing, so they are more lickly to get questions, when they have more upvotes in the tags then most people.

Answer (score 8):

As a workaround until you get an answer from *Stack Overflow*, you could do this with a [userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6771/review-tag-repositioner). I've posted one on Stack Apps.

It clones the tags and adds them to the top of the review content as pictured below.

[image: tag reposition]

Comment: This sounds really cool, but when I followed the link to *userscript*, I expected to find something describing the feature.   Can you point us at instructions on how to use this?

Comment: For js noobs like me follow [this installation instruction](https://superuser.com/questions/252046/how-do-i-install-a-userscript). Greasemonkey didn't work for whatever reason, but Tampermonkey did. Thanks for creating this script, which makes life easier.

Comment: Perhaps this is cool. But, IMHO, it encourages SO to be sloppy. If SO does not bother making the process convinient for reviewers, stop reviewing.

Answer (score -1):

I missed this question initially, when posted about the same thing, but nothing has changed in 7 years on this matter.

Seeing reaction on [my closed question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421285/place-question-tags-at-the-top-during-review), **I will not touch the review form ever again until the tags are moved to the top**. Reviewers are volunteers, in case Stack Overflow does not remember, and it is Stack Overflow’s responsibility to make the process convenient for them.

Probably, Stack Overflow will not lose much by losing one low ranked reviewer. The question is, though, whether the price will actually be just a single reviewer.