# Place question tags at the top during review

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, design

Please move question tags up in the review form. The tags should be placed immediately after the question title.

N.B.:
There are at least two similar questions, which I missed:
[Should tags be relocated to the top of question pages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338198/should-tags-be-relocated-to-the-top-of-question-pages)
[Show tags on top when reviewing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311043/show-tags-on-top-when-reviewing-questions)

I am keeping my question for now and leave it up to moderators to decide, whether it should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: What's the justification for doing that?  Would be good to know about since tags are something that makes sense after looking at the question, but that's just me.

Comment: If you want to know if the review is something for you prior reading the whole question, then use the tag filter instead.

Comment: Why? Tags help understand whether I should even spend my time looking at the question. They also help understand relevant question areas. They are there to help, so they should not be buried.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion now.

Comment: I know about the filter, but I want to see the tags write away. One does not replace the other.

Comment: Then why do you limit this feature to reviews instead of wanting it for all questions? Btw there have been similar requests: [Should tags be relocated to the top of question pages?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338198) (more in the comments there)

Comment: Indeed, it was asked at least twice before, 6 and 7 years ago. The comment there says something that the tags were supposedly moved in mobile apps. Suppose this comment is outdated. Anyways, I missed those questions, but I do support them.

Comment: Voting to close as duplicate of: [Show tags on top when reviewing questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311043/show-tags-on-top-when-reviewing-questions)

Comment: @tom because when you browse the question list, and you always normally do it first, the tags are prominently displayed. I do not mind, if the tags are moved up every where, but, imho, it would be most beneficial in review.

Comment: I mean... whatever people need to cause them to hit skip more, I'm in favor of it. It definitely won't hurt anyone to move the tags. I don't expect it to happen though since it just seems to be the same question rendering logic used everywhere on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment:

> Tags help understand whether I should even spend my time looking at the question. They also help understand relevant question areas. They are there to help, so they should not be buried.

You can filter out tags you don't want to review in general.

[image]

You shouldn't lean on this to eliminate every review question that isn't in your favorite technology; some questions can be reviewed absent context of a language, and *should* be reviewed absent context of a language.

Put more succinctly:  **if you're reviewing, then you should be reviewing the content irrespective of what tags are attached to it.**  You can filter a few out but that isn't the point here.

Comment: I said in the comment that I know about the filter and understand how to use it. And yes, you are right, just because a question does not have a specific tag, it does not mean I cannot review it. Which is also why the filter does replace the ability to see the tags. This is really weird. Why on Earth the tags were placed at the bottom in the first place. Browsing questions and reviewing them are two different things. When you go to question list, the tags are prominent. There is no similar thing in the review form, so the tags should have never been placed at the bottom to start with.

Comment: I understand your point, but it still for me to decide which questions to review. And SO should make it convenient to do the job. I do not see how this request could possibly considered unreasonable (see my comment above).

Comment: I don't follow your motivation for *needing* to see the tags at the top though @PChemGuy.  That is to say...your original justification was to determine if the question could be reviewed by you, to which the reply is, "filter out the ones you don't want to see".   There's a limited amount of filter slots, so the message that the system is sending is, "You should be reviewing questions no matter *what* they're tagged with."   So help me bridge that gap, would you?

Comment: Well, the reason is similar to why researches first read the title, then the abstract. Only then the may or may not read the other parts of the article. And when they do, knowledge of the abstract helps navigate the article and digest the content quicker. Tags may also help guess, for example, what to look for or what should not be expected. I do not know, I cannot articulate an exhaustive list. This meta data is there and it definitely saves time on average.

Comment: @PChemGuy:  But the point of this isn't that you're reading this like you would a question on the main site.  **You're reviewing this question.**  So you have to look over the details of the question.  And hey, if you *truly* can't make a determination on how to review the question, you could always just skip it.  The review system breaks (even further) if reviewers only hand-pick the kind of content they review, which leaves the content that they chose not to review in an even worse state.

Comment: @PChemGuy:  To riff on your example, a peer reviewer would probably want *some* context into the subject matter, but wouldn't explicitly look at only one time of article over other types of articles.

Comment: Peer reviewers do not review arbitrary articles. Most of the time, the editors chooses relevant experts in the field. Not just any chemists or physists, but researchers who publish and conduct research in the same or nearby area. So I might not be getting the thing about SO reviews to certain extend, but I AM coming from the academic background.

Comment: @PChemGuy:  Yes, so you filter out the stuff you *can't* and skip the stuff the filters don't cover.  But in general the big thing is that you are attempting to review as much as you can.

Comment: This is fine, and tags may very well still help even if I choose do deviate from where I fill comfortable.